# Calling an API using Axios and Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a Google Cloud Function calling an external API for me. After some research on Google I found the way using Axios. The call is actually working, when I'm using it on my own nodejs but when I want to deploy the function to Google Cloud functions I'm always getting an error (Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated.)

I'm on the Blaze plan.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");

exports.getData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return axios.get("http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key='myAccessKey'&symbols=AAPL")
      .then((response) => {
        const apiResponse = response.data;
        if (Array.isArray(apiResponse["data"])) {
          apiResponse["data"].forEach((stockData) => {
            console.log(stockData["symbol"]);
          });
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
});
```

Could someone please help me?

**EDIT:** I finally fixed it: the mistake was, that I ended up with two package.json files (one in the directory where it should be and one which I actually didn't need). When I was installing the dependencies with npm install, axios was added into the wrong package.json file. Unfortunately the other package.json file made it up to the server and I ended up with a package.json file without the necessary dependencies on the server and thus this made the error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn’t test your code but you should return "something" (a value, `null`, a Promise, etc.) in the `then()` block to indicate to the Cloud Function platform that the asynchronous work is complete. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in the doc for more details.

```
exports.getData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return axios.get("http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key='myAccessKey'&symbols=AAPL")
      .then((response) => {
        const apiResponse = response.data;
        if (Array.isArray(apiResponse["data"])) {
          apiResponse["data"].forEach((stockData) => {
            console.log(stockData["symbol"]);
          });
        }
        return null;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
});
```

You probably want do more than just logging values in the `then()` e.g. call an asynchronous Firebase method to write to a database (Firestore or the RTDB): in this case take care to return the Promise returned by this method.

Comment: Thank you very much - I already fount the mistake. Thank you very much for your support anyway (y)

Comment: Hey tomtom did my answer help you?